# QGIS crashes when using PostgreSQL/PostGIS triggers

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, trigger

When using PostgreSQL/PostGIS triggers saving layer edits gets slower and slower every time when saving a layer edit. This issue occurs after a few up to a few dozen saved layer edits. Finally QGIS freezes completely.

I've tried the posted triggers in the folowing link:

[How to use interacting PostgreSQL/PostGIS triggers in QGIS to create multiple labels on polygons?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/160320/how-to-use-interacting-postgresql-postgis-triggers-in-qgis)

Has anyone else made this observation? I've installed QGIS 2.12.

Comment: Have you checked to see if QGIS has any queries running in `pg_stat_activity`?

Comment: That behaviour sounds a lot like a bad plugin. Are you sure it's related to the triggers and not something else?